# Access Windows.Form of Unity standalone player for windows

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine, window

Is unity standalone player for Windows a `Windows.Form`? If so, how can we access its handle?

```
if(Form.ActiveForm != null)
{
   m_form = Form.ActiveForm;
   Debug.Log("m_form.Name");
}
```

I am using the `Mono` version of `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. I am trying the above code to access the `Form` handle but it always returns `null` even when window is active, which makes me doubt that standalone windows build is not a `Windows.Form`.

I basically need to access the toolbar so that I can change its color (Not title, for title we already have a workaround that doesn't require accessing the `Form` instance). Also, I need to set minimum size for the window. Any solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can always p/invoke winapi , so in order to get the handle of the current active window use this :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
```

And in order to move / adjust the position of the window u can use one of these :

[SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx), [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(VS.85).aspx) and [AdjustWindowRectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632667(VS.85).aspx)

and btw to get a the window's handle ..

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
```

or :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

Comment: What do we pass for ZeroOnly or lpClassName? And how can we use IntPtr as Form?

Comment: @HarshPriyadarshi i think i missunderstood the main question ,  this c++ function is used to get a Window's handle   is that what you are trying to achieve , or you just want to check if your current form is the current active or not ?

Comment: I want to access the Windows.Form of standalone build so that I can set its minimum size and tweak toolbar color.

Comment: @HarshPriyadarshi that's impossible , you will have to p/invoke winapi for that .